# ProcessPoolExecutor, some processes stuck at Sl+ state

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This is my code structure

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers = n) as executor:
    for i in range(k):
        executor.submit(func, i)
```

When I execute the code, around half of the processes fall into `Sl+` state within 6~8 seconds (each function takes around 20 seconds to run). Once the process run over 10 seconds, it runs stable until the loop finishes. Also, the function runs perfectly without multiprocessing (so I assume no error is raised during the run). The part of the function returns logs, which I cannot control.

What can be the possible problem? Or is there any way to figure out the process is stucked and re-run the process or something?

I initially suspect the logs might be the problem since writing a log may lock the memory temporarily, such that new process may get stucked. But given that the processes stuck after 6~8 seconds, this doesn't seem logical.

Comment: How large is `n`?  Are you submitting way more processes than you have CPUs?

Comment: @TimRoberts n is smaller than cpus...